# Batch or VBscirpt to copy only folder structure(Not Files) from one server to another server by giving folder structure as an separate input file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Example:

**Source:**
Server 1:
C:\Folder1\Test2
C:\Folder2\Test3
C:\Folder3\Test1

**Destination:**
Server 2:
(Same structure above should be copied here with permissions)

**Note**: In script, have to call the above folder structure(Server 1) in separate file (Ex: Flies.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Use Robocopy for this

```
 Robocopy "source" "destination" /e /xf *
```

Obviously replace source and destination with the actual source/destination directories!

The `/e` will copy empty directories. The `/xf *` will exclude files.

To exclude certain files, such as `txt` files then you could do

```
 Robocopy "source" "destination" /e /xf *.txt
```

Comment: I have used command **xcopy /t /e /o "source" "destination"** for coping folder structure from one location to another location in same server. Here i need to copy the folder structure to another server with same permission assigned to folders.

Comment: What do you mean by the same permissions? Do you mean keep the existing folder permissions of the source so they are copied to the destination?

Comment: Yes... Note: Users under folder permissions from source having access to destination as well

Comment: @Balaji Why does your OP not mention this? Your question is frankly, terrible. Also, how would this work if you try and copy a set of permissions on 1 machine which do not exist on another?